# getting a local copy of an aws rds snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

In AWS, I have snapshot continually being taken on a daily basis, and I need to be able to view the state of the database at the time a particular snapshot was taken (but I don't want to restore to the snapshot just yet). Is there any way to somehow download the snapshot via something like a mysql dump? Even if this can't be done directly is there a workaround?

Comment: You could launch a new RDS instance from the snapshot, and then export or view the data from that instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Snapshots cannot be downloaded. If you need to download it you should probably do MySQL backups to S3. Those are standard backups that can be used in another MySQL database server.

Comment: Technically they can be downloaded, just after they're exported to S3, it's just they're useless as they will be encrypted using KMS using key which you can't export.

Comment: No they're not: you don't download your exported snapshot "as files" from your bucket, you use the AWS CLI to sync your S3 bucket to your local drive, which will write perfectly usable files. But they _will_ be Apache Parquet files, so if that's not what you need, export to S3 is not going to be very useful.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans So wtf is the point of a snapshot to s3? There's no option to even restore it.

Comment: Easy enough to google and learn that it's https://parquet.apache.org - whether you want to use that is another matter, that's up to you. My guess for why you can't restore from S3 is because you can already restore the snapshot itself to a new, working database. So if you need a db to query (or dump), you wouldn't export to S3 in the first place, you'd just click "restore" and run through that process.

Answer (score 0):

My solution has been to ignore the S3 export and instead take the snapshot, turn that into its own temporary (postgres flavoured) database so that it can be connected to over the network. AWS might call it "restore" but they mean "restore it from a compressed snapshot archive to a working database", not "overwrite your existing database with this data". It restores your snapshot as a *new* database.

You can then use `pg_dump` to get a copy of the DB using the pg URL, and while that'll be slower than exporting to S3 (but since it's a snapshot, speed doesn't really matter) it has the upside of having useful data at the end of it rather than parquet files.

And then, of course, remember to delete the temporary database (and depending on whether it's a scheduled snapshot or a one-off, the snapshot itself)